# How update counter: set new value after avery request, NOT increment new value to previous value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, prometheus

want to create Prometheus client by python

[Tried to use this module](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python)

Took this code

```
from prometheus_client import Counter
c = Counter('my_requests_total', 'HTTP Failures', ['method', 'endpoint'])
c.labels(method='get', endpoint='/').inc()
c.labels(method='post', endpoint='/submit').inc()
```

All good, BUT I want to set new value after avery request, NOT increment new value to previous value.

How can make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Gauge and not a Counter.

Example from the README:

```
from prometheus_client import Gauge
g = Gauge('my_inprogress_requests', 'Description of gauge')
g.inc()      # Increment by 1
g.dec(10)    # Decrement by given value
g.set(4.2)   # Set to a given value
```

See also Prometheus metric types: https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/

> **Counter**
>
> A counter is a cumulative metric that represents a single numerical value that only ever goes up. A counter is typically used to count requests served, tasks completed, errors occurred, etc. Counters should not be used to expose current counts of items whose number can also go down, e.g. the number of currently running goroutines. Use gauges for this use case.
>
> **Gauge**
>
> A gauge is a metric that represents a single numerical value that can arbitrarily go up and down.
>
> Gauges are typically used for measured values like temperatures or current memory usage, but also "counts" that can go up and down, like the number of running goroutines.

Answer (score 0):

Counter value can be set by accessing private `_value` property. ***I strongly recommend avoiding this solution, unless you know for sure that the values you are going to set will only increase and not decrease***. Otherwise use `Gauge` instead.

```py
from prometheus_client import Counter
c = Counter("foo", "bar")
c._value.set(50)
c._value.get()
50
c._value.set(101)
c._value.get()
101

# the same with labels
cd = Counter("bar", "foo", labelnames=['name'])
cd.labels(name="spam")._value.set(20)
```

#### What can go wrong with this approach

The main problem is the counter reset. Whenever PromQL functions (such as `rate()`, `increase()`) detect a counter decrease, it is considered as a reset. Consider this simple example:

```
my_metric            1 2 3 4 3
increase(my_metric)  0 1 1 1 3
```

So if you decrease a counter value, some functions will treat it as if counter became 0 and then instantly went up to whichever value it is now. This will ruin all calculations on that counter, especially if it's a big one (like sent bytes, requests handled, etc).